# Display current Julian Date in web part

Tags: javascript, web-part, html, date, html-form-web-part

Is it possible to display the current 4 digit Julian date (YDDD) at the top of a column above a web part?

I've been trying to google and insert a javascript code in the modify HTML portion when editing the page, but I am not very good at coding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Little code fragment to assist with conversion to and from Julian date format.

```
public static long ToJulian(DateTime dateTime)
{
    int day = dateTime.Day;
    int month = dateTime.Month;
    int year = dateTime.Year;

    if (month < 3)
    {
        month = month + 12;
        year = year - 1;
    }

    return day + (153 * month - 457) / 5 + 365 * year + (year / 4) - (year / 100) + (year / 400) + 1721119;
} 

public static string FromJulian(long julianDate, string format) 
{ 
    long L = julianDate + 68569; 
    long N = (long) ((4*L)/146097); 
    L = L - ((long)((146097 * N + 3)/4) ); 
    long I = (long) ((4000 *(L + 1)/1461001)) ; 
    L = L - (long)((1461*I)/4) + 31;  
    long J = (long)((80*L)/2447);  
    int Day = (int)(L - (long)((2447*J)/80)); 
    L=(long)(J/11) ; 
    int Month = (int)(J + 2 - 12*L); 
    int Year = (int)(100*(N-49) + I + L) ; 

    // example format "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return new DateTime(Year,Month,Day).ToString(format); 
}
```

Comment: Is above solution works for you?

Comment: I couldn't get this script to work. I'm far from an expert, but it doesn't seem to follow the same format as the html scripts I see when I edit the page through share point editor.

Comment: Still no solution on this questions. The answer posted was a copy/paste from yahoo answers. It did not work.